# Wait with image replace until image is loaded

Tags: jquery, image, loading

I have a working script *(thanks stackexchange!)* for exchanging an image on the fly. I use it as a gallery script. It looks like this:

```
           $(".source a").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var $a = $(this);
                $("#targetcontainer img").hide("puff", function(){
                    $(this).attr("src", $a.attr("href")).show("fold");
                });
            });
```

The problem regarding this script is that the old image flickers after the JQ show command. The new source Image shows up a second or so later which makes a weird effect. how can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could preload the image before attempting to display it...

```
$(".source a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var newSrc = this.href,
        image = new Image();    

    image.onload = function() {
        $("#targetcontainer img").hide("puff", function() {
            $(this).attr("src", newSrc).show("fold");
        });
    }
    image.src = newSrc;
});
```

Comment: if it's in a loop, make sure to set the final img src to the image.src because it is asynchronous. otherwise, they'll all be set to to whatever the variable is at the time.

Answer (score 11):

In JQuery there is **load** event.

1) Retrieve image.

```
var image = $("#img");
image.hide();
```

2) On load do something.

```
image.load(function(){
 image.show();
});
```

3) Change src attribute to fire load event after image has changed.

```
image.attr("src","image.jpg");
```

You can read more about it in here: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: I think as of jQUery 3 load does something different? This just downloads the image now :D

Comment: Please note that the load function has to be changed to something like ```image.on('load', function(){ });``` on newer versions of jQuery.

Comment: please note, if you are reusing an existing `img` element from DOM, it is possible you will be attaching multiple `onload` callbacks to the same element. You could use `.off('load').on('load', function(){})`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make this work in all browsers with the minimal amount of delay is to use [CSS sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites).

If that's not an option for you, you could pre-load the image somewhere and make it invisible -- the browser will load the image early, and won't delay when your JQuery exectues.

Comment: Sprites dont work for this as this is a gallery. Thanks though!