# Is there a way to fade in and out the same image URL on loop with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have an image stored on the webserver (example.com/webcam.jpg) that is updated server-side.

I would like to insert this image on a static HTML page but with a loop that keeps reloading the image (possibly fading from the previous to the current image)

There are jquery examples that fades between 2 images with 2 different addresses, but in my case, the image is always stored at the same URL and the loop/fade has to continue until the user leaves the page.

So far all I'm doing to keep it functional but not very pleasing, is using `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">` to refresh the whole page.

Comment: Your suggestion answers about what brand of oil to use in a car while my question is more about still getting a driving license. :) I didn't think about the issues with caching, I'm still trying to figure out how to reload the image in loop (with a fade effect), probably my initial question was not clear enough, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` to setup a loop.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

In the loop, set the image `src=` to your source image, but this will not refresh your image as it will be cached by the browser, so you need to add something to the URL so the browser thinks it's a new image.

```
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("myimage").src = "/myimage.jpg" + new Date().getTime();
}, 5000);
```

You can add a simple fadeIn/fadeOut

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#myimage").fadeOut(function() {
        this.src = "/myimage.jpg" + new Date().getTime();
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
}, 5000);
```

It would be better to wait for the image to finish loading, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5789300/2181514

For an even smoother effect, you could use two images like the answers you already found then there would be no need to hide one while the other is loading.  Place them on top of each other using `position:relative` / `position:absolute` then fadeIn one while fadeOut the other to get them to transition (but not really part of this question, just to improve the UX).